# Google Maps clear placed MarkerClusters on new search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble getting my map to clear the clusters on a new search.  Any ideas?

```
function clearLocations() {
    //infoWindow.close();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers.length = 0;

    // clear #side_bar bottom text
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = "";
    // clear .alertBox text
    $('.alertBox').html('');
}


function searchLocationsNear(center) {
    clearLocations();

    var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng();
    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function (data) {
        var xml = parseXml(data);
        var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        if (markerNodes.length > 0) {

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
                var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
                var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
                var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
                var category = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("category");
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

                // createOption(name, distance, i);
                createMarker(latlng, name, address, category);
                bounds.extend(latlng);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            var markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
          // markerclusterer.setMap(null);
            makeSidebar(); 

        } else {
            $('.alertBox').html('Sorry, there are no jobs that are close to your location.');
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
if (markers) {
    for (i in markers) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    markerclusterer.clearMarkers()
}
```

According to the [docs](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) the clusterer can be clear with `clearMarkers()` method.

**UPDATE**

Call clear only when we have already create the MarkerClusterer.

```
if(markerclusterer)
{
    clearLocations();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I receive "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clearMarkers' of undefined"

Comment: Because you call `clearLocations` before creating the markerclusterer on the first time. You should do this after or like my update :)

Comment: I answered your question ?

Comment: `markerclusterer` is only visible in `searchLocationsNear`, not in `clearLocations`

Comment: Yes, I know, you need to put the `if` here.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I understand your answer.  It's not in the scope, but I'm still not able to clear.  Any other ideas?  Thank you.